# Symfony array to string DataTransformer exception

Tags: php, symfony

I have the User entity with the email string field. Actually i have the emails CollectionType field in the UserType from which the email string is obtained using a transformer.

For some reason, if the object is passed to the form and has a non-null email field value, then I get an exception.

> Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "string" given.

It works with null.

**Code of transformer:**

```
/**
 * @param string|null $email
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function transform($email)
{
    if (!$email) {
        return [];
    }

    return [
        [
            'primary' => true,
            'type'    => 'work',
            'value'   => $email,
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * @param array|ArrayCollection|null $data
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function reverseTransform($data)
{
    if (!$data) {
        return null;
    }

    foreach ($data as $email) {
        if ($email['primary']) {
            return $email['value'];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Email string from emails array\collection coming in the request is successfully inserted into the field on entity creating.

If the email field already contains a string, then the form doesn't even go into that section of code.